# Using XQuery to search for Node having specific details

Tags: xml, xpath, xml-parsing, xquery

I'm not an expert in XQuery and I'm having to search though big collection of files,
the XML doc have a structure like this,

```
<files>
<file>
    <name>1</name>
    <contents>
        <content>games</content>
        <content>movies</content>
    </contents>
</file>
<file>
    <name>2</name>
    <contents>
        <content>games</content>
        <content>picture</content>
        <content>work</content>
    </contents>
</file>
```

its like the user i have a set of content like may be ("games","movies") and I have to return the name

so far i wrote only this

```
for $x in /files/file
    return $x/content
```

I want to know whether this is possible with XQuery? if possible, just give me some guidelines, i'm not aware of all xquery constructs, thats my main drawback

Comment: You haven't made it clear what your input is: is it one XML document with lots of elements named "file", or is it lots of files each containing an XML document? And you haven't made it clear what your desired output is. Do you want the name of every file? In that case it's simply `/files/file/name`.

Comment: it is a single XML files, containing all 'file' tag in 'files' tag

Comment: Could you maybe illustrate what you want as output?  Will it be text, XML, HTML, or something else?  When you say "I have to return the name," do you mean that for each file you want to produce a list of "names" (i.e., "content" element contents)?  If so, does that list come in the form of a comma-separated list, say, or what?  And do you need to associate the file identities with the "names?"  A sample of what you're looking for would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

you have to provide the `contents` element also in the xpath as it contains the `content` element values. 
you can try out this if u want only the values of `content`

```
for $x in /files/file/contents/content
return xs:string($x)
```

you can also try this

```
for $x in /files/file/contents/content
return $x/text()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
let $data:=
<files>
<file>
    <name>1</name>
    <contents>
        <content>games</content>
        <content>movies</content>
    </contents>
</file>
<file>
    <name>2</name>
    <contents>
        <content>games</content>
        <content>picture</content>
        <content>work</content>
    </contents>
</file>
</files>

for $cont in $data//content
return element contents{$cont}
```